# How to get tests in unit test project to be run (when the method has parameters)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, seed

I have a unit test I want to named parameters in, e.g:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Register(bool DoSeed = false, AccountViewModelForReg VM = null)
{
    AutoMapperConfig.Configure(); //TODO move to global

    AccountController C = new AccountController();
    VM = new AccountViewModelForReg()
    {
        Username = "testuser1",
        Password = AccountHelper.HashPassword("a"),
        Email = "testuser1"+CommonEmailSuffix,
        Email2 = "testuser1"+CommonEmailSuffix
    };
    var Result = C.Register(VM, true) as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("Register", Result.ViewName);
}
```

This is so from my EF Seeder, I can use my unit tests to seed, by just passing parameters in. But because the method takes parameters, Visual Studio doesn't count it as a test to be run. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend MSTest to allow this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, VS unit test don't support parameterized unit tests.
Your only way is to write another, parameterless overload and call your method from there. BTW: The optional parameters are nothing but syntactical sugar; the method still requires the parameters.

Example:

```
public void Test_One(bool p1, string p2)
//...
public void Test_One()
{
   Test_One(true, "defaultvalue");
}
```

You should take a look at another framework, e.g. NUnit, which allows you to easily parametrize your tests (even with ranges, automatic combination of parameters etc.): See http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5